# Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/index.js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I was installing a react startup app and added Webpack, but it says `Can't resolve './src/index.js'`.

**Browser Shows**
[image: My app gives this look]

**My Files Path and Package.json Contents** 
[image]

**Webpack.config.js** Contents

```
 var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    var path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
        context: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : false,
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2016', 'stage-0'],
                    plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties'],
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/public/",
        filename: "build.js"
    },
    plugins: debug ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
    ],
};
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your base URL is `path.join(__dirname, "public")`, and your entry is `./src/index.js`. Webpack tries to find `./src/index.js` in `public` dir; obviously it does not exist.  You should modify `entry` to `../src/index.js`.

Comment: Thanks @kermit `ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2016" relative to directory "C:\\Users\\ashik\\Desktop"`

But I get new Error

Comment: Worked in my case with .. in a similar import error, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The other way I find out to fix this problem is to use `path.resolve()`.

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + 'path/to/your/file.js',
    output: {
        /*Webpack producing results*/
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/dist"),
        filename: "app-bundle.js"
    }
}
```

This will make sure, webpack is looking for entry point in `src` directory.

By the way it's the default entry point. You can also change this entry point to your suitable location. Just replace the `src` directory with the other directory you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

My webpack.config.js was named Webpack.config.js and the new cli was looking for something case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Webpack does not look for .js files by default. You can configure resolve.extensions to look for .ts. Don't forget to add the default values as well, otherwise most modules will break because they rely on the fact that the .js extension is automatically used.

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The entry path is relative to the context. It's looking for a file in `public/src/` when you want it to look for a path in just `/src`. Looking at the rest of your `webpack.config.js` it doesn't seem like you need the context line at all.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found that it was caused by having installed `create-react-app` globally in the past using `npm install -g create-react-app`.

As create-react-app should now not be installed globally, I needed to uninstall it first using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and then install it in my project directory with `npx create-react-app *my-app-name*`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to put App.js file on a components folder inside the src folder and keep the inde.js just inside the src one

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. And solutions was really 'at the top' I forgot to add `module.exports` inside my *webpack.prod.js*.

So instead of

```
merge(common, {
...
});
```

use

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
...
});
```