# Webpack 4: ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src'

Tags: webpack

This is a duplicate question but I want to use custom entry instead of default to webpack 4 entry as been suggested in the post [Webpack 4: Error in entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772863/webpack-4-error-in-entry-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-src)

webpack.dev.config.js:

```
import path from 'path';

export default {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './app/components/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: 'babel-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

[image: Project Structure]

The following errors are shown when running **webpack-wd**

> Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found. Alternatively, run
>   'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.
>
> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in
>   'C:\Patient_Check_In'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [commonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) module syntax for webpack configuration:

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './app/components/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0"
  }
}
```

**app/compontens/index.js**

```js
console.log('hello!');
```

If you run `webpack` a file called *bundle.js* is generated in the *dist* folder, that file contains all babel pollyfills, plus webpack runtime, plus your app (in this case a simple console.log statement). If you want you can set a specific babel configuration.

Comment: It works. I edited my answer to show you the rest of my test repository. Try it yourself. You probably have some other code in your configuration that create that bug.

Comment: By default webpack finds the config file 'webpack.config.js'. If you specify custom config file, like the one provided in this issue, you can run: 'webpack --config webpack.dev.config.js'

Comment: You are right. I didn't notice in your screenshot that you use a different naming for the default webpack config. Anyway as good practice I suggest you to use the default config name and import other configs (based on your environment) inside it. If you want to learn more this guide may help: https://survivejs.com/webpack/developing/composing-configuration/

Comment: This got me closer. Still need to resolve node_modules for some reason. Thanks mate!